# Azure App registeration vs Enterprise Applications

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have seen that some Services can add an entry into my ActiveDirectory-> EnterpriseApplications page when i just enter my Azure Account UserId and Password on their page. Using this they can use Azure RestAPI and get List of my subscriptions and Resources etc.

Even I have created a custom web Application(hosted on some public server) and I want to access Subscriptions and Resources of users using the REST API. But to do that it asks me to do the AppRegistration. But i do not want every user to do App Registration, rather i want to add that entry in AppRegistration programatically using some sort of REST based API, all they have to do is provide me access to an account that has the necessary rights. However i am unable to find any documentation for this.

There is a threads which say its possible but fail to provide any necessary references https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/d9bfefbf-d1ea-4ba1-bd28-5379caab0e33/azure-programatically-add-entry-into-app-registrations-in?forum=WindowsAzureAD

--------------Edit----------------
Thanks juunas

The MS documentation is really confusing, I use this .net code to get some "code", but what do we do with this code.

```
string authorizationRequest = String.Format(
                "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&state={2}&scope={3}",
                 Uri.EscapeDataString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientID"]),
                 Uri.EscapeDataString("mywebsite.com"),
                 Uri.EscapeDataString(stateMarker), "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
                 );
```

This code does not work

```
            ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientID"],
                                                               ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Password"]);
            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/");
            AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                code, new Uri("mywebsite.com"), credential);
```

and gives an error, also there seems to be two kinds of API v1.0 and v2.0. Also there is another page here where we need to add App Registrations, dont know why MS created 2 pages https://apps.dev.microsoft.com
 If I dont create application here and create it on the Azure portal I get this error when I run the first part of the code

error=unauthorized_client&error_description=The+client+does+not+exist.+If+you+are+the+application+developer%2c+configure+a+new+application+through+the+application+management+site+at+https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/.

Comment: I think you can create Multi-tenant App and you only need to do application registration once. Users in other tenant can just use it if they do permissions consent to it.

Comment: Link here says https://explore.emtecinc.com/blog/an-overview-of-azure-ad-multi-tenant-authentication that we still need ApppRegsitration entry, and these are not multiple tenants in single User Account, these are single tenants of mutiple Azure User Account

Comment: This is exactly the scenario for multi-tenant apps. The way it works is you create the App Registration (Application) in your tenant, which also creates the Enterprise Application (Service principal) in your tenant. Then when another tenant user wants to login to your app, they grant your app the permissions it requires and the Enterprise Application (Service Principal) is created in their tenant. This SP effectively mirrors your application in their tenant.

Comment: Please refer to the edit section for the followup