# Not able to get group info of another tenant using Microsoft graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have created two directories in Azure AD portal. In one directory, I registered client application and given delegated permissions

- User.Read
- Directory.AccessAsUser.All
- Directory.Read.All

I also made it Multitenant for any Azure AD directory to use this application.

After successful login, I call API (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf) to get groups information of the user. This works only for the users in directory where application is registered. I do get all details such displayName etc for the user in directory where app is registered.

When I login through user belonging to another tenant (directory), login is successful but I do not get complete group data in API response (included below). I get correct object id (of group) back though but not the other details.

It seems to be permission related issue which I am not able to figure out. Anyone please suggest.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#directoryObjects",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.group",
            "id": "8bcd8779-8a74-4db7-83f0-8a5c5d076540",
            "deletedDateTime": null,
            "classification": null,
            "createdDateTime": null,
            "creationOptions": [],
            "description": null,
            "displayName": null,
            "groupTypes": [],
            "isAssignableToRole": null,
            "mail": null,
            "mailEnabled": null,
            "mailNickname": null,
            "onPremisesDomainName": null,
            "onPremisesLastSyncDateTime": null,
            "onPremisesNetBiosName": null,
            "onPremisesSamAccountName": null,
            "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null,
            "onPremisesSyncEnabled": null,
            "preferredDataLocation": null,
            "proxyAddresses": [],
            "renewedDateTime": null,
            "resourceBehaviorOptions": [],
            "resourceProvisioningOptions": [],
            "securityEnabled": null,
            "securityIdentifier": null,
            "visibility": null,
            "onPremisesProvisioningErrors": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I use spring security oauth2 implementation with these configuration properties (id, secret masked)

```
azure:
  activedirectory:
    tenant-id: 66aeb78f-7a26-46c9-99ab-460c6309b21e
    active-directory-groups: Users
  client:
    client-id: 9618ac61-43ab-4c97-a9f1-769c91f48e08
    client-secret: DxndD0cBezR-AnrGuCH@?b1NpwtFj?47
    accessTokenUri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
    userAuthorizationUri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?prompt=select_account
    scope: user.read
  resource:
    userInfoUri: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
```

Comment: Can you share how you are obtaining the access token to call Microsoft Graph?

Comment: first get spring security authentication object (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()) and then get the token from the authentication object. I have updated question with configuration properties

Comment: Now that you put the client secret in the cloud, you may want to change it...

Comment: Thanks for alert but I had posted "altered" client secret and ids.

Answer (score 1):

When the only property populated is the object ID, you are likely in the scenario described in [Limited information returned for inaccessible member objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/permissions-reference#limited-information-returned-for-inaccessible-member-objects).

In short, while your app *does* have permission to read the fact that the signed-in user is a member of the group (thanks to *User.Read*) it does *not* have permission to read all the properties of that group.

Since *Directory.Read.All* would be sufficient to read all group properties, a likely conclusion is that in the second tenant, your app has not actually been granted all three permissions you list, and has only been granted *User.Read*.

Note: Always choose the least-privileged permissions for your scenario. *Directory.AccessAsUser.All* should be avoided wherever possible as it's the *most* privileged permission. For the scenario you're described, you may not even need *Directory.Read.All*. If you only need access to basic group details (e.g. display name, etc.), try [*GroupMember.Read.All*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#group-permissions) instead.

Comment: First I tried with Group.Read.All which did not work so thought to try with Directory.Read.All

Answer (score 0):

Taking pointer from Philippe's response, I searched where and how to grant permission in second tenant. These links have helped me to understand difference between app registration and enterprise apps.

[Azure App registeration vs Enterprise Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51341938/azure-app-registeration-vs-enterprise-applications)

[Difference between "enterprise application" and "app registration" in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54071385/difference-between-enterprise-application-and-app-registration-in-azure/)